# How to get last modified time of a ftp file [in epoc millisecs format] in python using FTP from ftplib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp, ftplib

In python,

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP("speedtest.tele2.net")
ftp.login("anonymous", "abc@gmail.com")
ftp.cwd("/upload")
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

Above code gives output like below:

```
-rw-------    1 105      108      34731200   Oct 05 17:50 100MB.zip
-rw-------    1 105      108      17404256   Oct 05 17:44 1_7708308143086291200_17-9ULspeedtest.upt
-rw-------    1 105      108       3889879   Oct 05 17:48 1_890431022834275069_17-9ULspeedtest.upt
-rw-------    1 105      108      8239537808 Oct 05 17:50 Die.glorreichen.Sieben.2016.German.1080p.DL.DTSHD.BluRay.AVC.Remux-pmHD.mkv
-rw-------    1 105      108        277504   Oct 05 17:50 _verizon_Quectel_COM57_512KB.zip
```

I am interested to get the last-modified-time of a file in epoch milliseconds. How to get it ?

Comment: Does your edit to the question title mean that you are not satisfied with my answer to the duplicate question? - My answer summarizes **all the options** you have to retrieve timestamp using FTP protocol. If none of the options listed there give you milliseconds, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

The FTP protocol does not standardize the output format of the `LIST` command.  What you see is all what you get.  You could try `LIST --full-time` and see if you get ISO output with microseconds, but this is a bit of a stretch.  it does not appear to work with the server in question.

The server supports the `MDTM` command, so you can at least get the modification time in seconds this way, but apparently it does not work in the `/upload` directory; it may need read access on the files for some reason.  Access to millisecond information does not seem to be supported.